# How to handle exception when doing request to external service and return status accordingly in Micronaut filter

Tags: rx-java2, micronaut, rx-kotlin2

So I'm completely new to rx-java/rx-kotlin and haven't heard about it until I where to write a HTTP filter in Micronaut (https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#filters) which caught me off guard since I've only done regular JAX-RS filters.

So after doing some trial-and-error I came up with this.

```
 return Flowable.fromPublisher(remoteClient.getPermissions(userId))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .onErrorReturn { e ->
            logger.error("Error when fetching users from remote service", e)
            emptyList()
        }
        .switchMap { permissions ->
            if (permissions.contains(somePermission)) {
                chain.proceed(request)
            } else {
                val response = HttpResponseFactory.INSTANCE.status(
                    HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,
                    "No user found"
                )
                Flowable.just(response)
            }
        }
```

Code is rewritten but point still stands. There's some room for improvement here.

What I'd like to do is to improve the exception handling and return a 500 in the case an exception is thrown (like if the remote service called by `remoteClient` isn't reachable. How can I accomplish this? I haven't got anything else to work other than the solution above to return an empty list for the next observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `onErrorReturn` operator after the `switchMap` operator. If `getPermissions` emits an error, execution will skip your `switchMap`, and pick up inside of `onErrorReturn`:

```kotlin
 return Flowable.fromPublisher(remoteClient.getPermissions(userId))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .switchMap { permissions ->
            if (permissions.contains(somePermission)) {
                chain.proceed(request)
            } else {
                val response = HttpResponseFactory.INSTANCE.status(
                    HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,
                    "No user found"
                )
                Flowable.just(response)
            }
        }
        .onErrorReturn { e ->
            logger.error("Error when fetching users from remote service", e)
            val response = // whatever
            return response
        }
```

Note that an exception occurring inside of `switchMap` will also result in `onErrorReturn` getting executed. So you either want to examine the Exception that is passed into  `onErrorReturn` to decide what response to use, or embed an `onErrorReturn` inside of `switchMap`, chained to the `chain.proceed(request)` call, to prevent it from emitting an exception downstream.